# Setting SSRS BackgroundImage Source from field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on an SSRS template at present which pulls lots of its format information from a database. Part of this format information sets the Background Image of cells.

I'm currently filling the image by setting the Source to External and pulling its value from the database. This works lovely, however It means pulling the image from a network source each time and while a small efficiency hit, I'd like to try and remove that pull if possible by embedding the standard images.

Again this works fine, I can pull either an external image or an embedded image and display on screen.  The problem comes when I'd like the option to do either.
I find that I cannot set the image Source from a field, there isn't an option in the GUI.

[image: Option missing from GUI]

I've tried going into the code and entering the details there but I get a validation error:

> The 'http://scemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition:Source' element is invalid - The value `=First(Fields!bodyBackgroundImageSource.Value, "dsTemplate")` is invalid according to its datatype `String` - The Enumeration constraint failed".

[image]

[image]

Has anyone else come across this and found a solution or know of a workaround? I can continue using only external images, but would prefer to avoid as many external calls as possible.

Comment: It sounds like a string to enum constraint check is failing. Can you check the spelling of all of your values that come back in bodyBackgroundImageSource and make sure they all match the ImageSource enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

In our local environment, we tested this scenario and if the expression can return the correct image name, then the image can display properly. You can check if the "First(Fields!bodyBackgroundImageSource.Value, "dsTemplate")" expression return the image name existing under Images folder on Report Data window. And make sure the image source is embedded.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the response. I see where your coming from with this however our problem is slightly different. We have an embedded image that we'd like to use as standard but have the facility to pull an image from a non-embedded source if we want to put in a major change across all reports based on this template. So we were hoping to be able to point the image at either an embedded image or an external file. Problem being we can't change the source setting.